# Angular material CDK drag and drop is way too slow in IE and Edge?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material2, angular-cdk

CDK drag and drop is way too slow in IE and Edge. only 1 sec after dragging, the placeholder and preview are appearing. Moving across the drop ranges is also lagging. But in Firefox and chrome it works perfect.

I have a loop of large data, 50-100 headers each will act as a drop zone. Each item within this header acts as droppable element. All are placed under cdkDropListGroup. The functionality works perfectly in all browsers. Only the movement of dragged element across these headers are too slow in IE and Edge. Below is the code sample,

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 right-mapping" cdkDropListGroup>
   <div class="drag-limit"
   ...
   <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of itemsToDrop; let ind=index">
       <div cdkDropList
          (cdkDropEntered)="entered($event)"
          [cdkDropListData]="item.children"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event,item,ind)">
        <ul>
         <li
            *ngFor="let childItem of item.children; let cind=index"
             (cdkDragStarted)="cdkDragStarted($event,childItem, ind, cind)" 
             (cdkDragReleased)="cdkDragReleased($event,ind, cind)"
             cdkDragBoundary=".drag-limit"
             cdkDrag
             vsDragScroll
             [vsDragScrollContainer]="dragLimit">
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   ...
  </div>
 </div>
```

When scrolling through the values in a large list the drop zone is not getting detected properly especially after scrolling. Thus i used a package ngx-drag-scroll. It was perfect and the drop zone detection was working perfectly. I removed this vsDragScroll and also checked if its causing issue. But still the issue persisted.

- Angular CLI: 7.3.8
- Node: 11.9.0
- Angular: 7.2.12
- Browsers:
- Chrome: 75.0(works)
- Firefox: 68.0.1 (works)
- IE: 11.22 (slow)
- Edge: 38.14(slow)